# Header set cookie not working in shopify extension

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, header, shopify

I'm working on shopify extension on php codeigniter. 7.1 php version.
I'm receiving this error while i'm installing extension on shopify.
The app couldn’t be loaded
Then i add this code in the default controller:

```
header('Set-Cookie: same-site-cookie=foo; SameSite=Lax');
header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

But still i'm receiving above error. Even the cookie was created as i check it on `Application > Storage > Cookies.`
Can anyone guide me that what is missing or why i'm still getting this error on chrome 80.
Thanks!
Find the attachments.
https://ibb.co/fFpSsZj
https://ibb.co/LdT6Zdq

Comment: What error are you receiving? Please include it in your question

Comment: Why you are not using `setcookie()` instead?

Comment: @mitkosoft `setcookie()` does not support the `SameSite` attribute, that's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine now. The solution is to go to **chrome://flags** and search for samesite and try to disable **SameSite by default cookies** and **Cookies without SameSite must be secure** options. Go to your app again, the error will hide. then go to Application > Storage > Cookies and check the app cookie which was created already. It may be include session id in the cookie. just replace this cookie including this `SameSite=none, secure` with same name,values etc and then again revert your flags settings and reload the app. It will work fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why did you decide that cookie is an issue? You might want to check the path to your app in settings or some other internal errors.

Anyway, if you're sure the problem is in your cookies - what you're trying to set up, just doesn't make any sense. I assume you just found an example somewhere and tried blindly add this into your app, without understanding.

1. Use the second construction. That's an example required for cookies set up from within the embedded application to work.
2. `cross-site-cookie=bar` is just an example of a cookie to set up. You should replace this with your key-value pair everywhere you're setting up cookies in your app.
3. Add `false` as a second parameter to the `header()` function to allow setting up multiple cookies at a time.

Here's an example:

```
header('Set-Cookie: username=John; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure', false);
header('Set-Cookie: age=30; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure', false);
```

Comment: I'm following this example:
[link](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/php.md)
But now i update some code in cookie and pass session value as a cross-site-cookie value. Cookie is successfully created and displaying. but it stills display an error message on shopify.
The app couldn’t be loaded.
Check the above attachments in the question.

Comment: Try to clear cache/cookies and load your app again. If would not help, go to `chrome://flags`, search for `samesite` and try to disable **SameSite by default cookies** and **Cookies without SameSite must be secure** options. Go to your app again, it must load well now. Once loaded, check cookies and its attributes set up by your application, find the ones that don't use `SameSite=None; Secure`, fix them. Set the above flags back to `Default` and try to load your app again.